Rename the [merkle-damgard] tag to [merkle-damgaard]
I noticed that merkle-damgard is spelled incorrectly. Correct spelling would be Damgård, but if å cannot be used in a tag name for technical reasons, it can be substituted by aa. I tried to use the edit link to rename it from merkle-damgard to merkle-damgaard, but that apparently allows editing of all the text but not the name itself.
The tag is named after Ivan Damgård, a Danish cryptographer. The wikipedia article for Å says:

International transcription
Alternative spellings of the Scandinavian Å have become a concern because of globalization, and particularly because of the popularization of the World Wide Web. This is to a large extent due to the fact that internet domains containing Scandinavian letters are not recognized by the DNS system, and do not feature on keyboards adapted for other languages. While it is recommended to keep the Å intact wherever possible, the next best thing is to use the older, double A spelling (e.g. "www.raade.com" instead of "www.råde.com"). This is because, as previously discussed, the Å/Aa indicates a separate sound. If the Å is represented as a common A without the ring (e.g. "www.rade.com") there is no indication that the A is supposed to represent another sound entirely. Even so, (mis-)representing the Å as just an A is particularly common in Sweden, as compared to Norway and Denmark.


In the worst case event that it cannot be renamed, there are only 12 questions tagged, so I don't think it would be too disruptive to retag them all.

If we rename it, we should add a synonym, since many users (like myself) will try to spell it with one a.

Tags can be renamed, but I'm not sure if any diamond mod can do that, or if it's limited to employees.

I don't think changing it to another incorrect spelling with the aa is worth it. If it's renamed to use å, the current one should become a synonym.

I merged the tag merkle-damgard into merkle-damgaard. In effect (I guess because the latter tag didn't exist yet), this renamed the tag and created a new tag synonym.
So, to answer CodesInChaos' hidden question, it is possible.
It is unfortunately not possible to use non-ASCII letters in Tag names (this seems to be a limitation of the Stack Exchange engine, or its configuration for our site).
